# Events are not Pushing to Kafka in Cassandra CDC

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, debezium

I am using Cassandra 3.11.13 database and debezium jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-cassandra-4/1.9.2.Final/debezium-connector-cassandra-4-1.9.2.Final-jar-with-dependencies.jar and kafka version 2.12.When I run the jar with below properties. Respective topic got created in the kafka but events are not seen in the kafka.

This is configuration Property

```
connector.name=test_connector
commit.log.relocation.dir=/home/techuser/cassandra-3.11.13/data/relocation/
http.port=8000
cassandra.config=/home/techuser/cassandra-3.11.13/conf/cassandra.yaml
cassandra.hosts=localhost 
cassandra.port=9042
kafka.producer.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
kafka.producer.retries=3 
kafka.producer.retry.backoff.ms=1000
kafka.topic.prefix=test_prefix
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
offset.backing.store.dir=/home/techuser/cassandra-3.11.13/data/
offset.flush.interval.ms=60000  
max.offset.flush.size=5000
cdc.dir.poll.interval.ms=2000  
snapshot.consistency=ONE
snapshot.mode=NEVER  
latest.commit.log.only=false
```

In the log I am able to see like this

```
04:15:41.440 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue - checking for more records...
04:15:41.440 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue - no records available yet, sleeping a bit...
04:15:41.440 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue - checking for more records...
04:15:41.440 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue - no records available yet, sleeping a bit...
04:15:41.441 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue - checking for more records...
04:15:41.441 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue - polling records...
04:15:41.441 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue - no records available yet, sleeping a bit...
04:15:41.463 [pool-4-thread-2] INFO io.debezium.connector.cassandra.AbstractDirectoryWatcher - No commitLogFile is detected in /home/techuser/arjun/cassandra-3.11.13/data/cdc_raw.
04:15:41.464 [pool-4-thread-2] DEBUG io.debezium.connector.cassandra.Cassandra4CommitLogProcessor - Processing commitLogFiles while initial is false
04:15:41.464 [pool-4-thread-2] INFO io.debezium.connector.cassandra.AbstractDirectoryWatcher - Polling commitLog files from /home/techuser/arjun/cassandra-3.11.13/data/cdc_raw ...
04:15:42.441 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue - checking for more records...
04:15:42.441 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue - no records available yet, sleeping a bit...
```

My Cassandra Keyspace and Table Details Mentioned Below

```
CREATE KEYSPACE datamountaineer WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE datamountaineer.foo (
    a int PRIMARY KEY,
    b text
) WITH additional_write_policy = '99p'
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND cdc = true
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '16', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND extensions = {}
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair = 'BLOCKING'
    AND speculative_retry = '99p';
```

Insert Command

```
insert into foo (a,b) values (5,'John');
```

Comment: Please share logs from after connector started

Comment: I had added the logs in the post which I am getting after connector started.

Comment: Well, there's no error. As it says - `no records available yet`, so what data is available in the database?

Comment: I had Created a Sample Keyspace and Created table in the Keyspace with cdc enabled true.

Comment: Okay, but have you inserted data into the table for any records _to be available_? Please [edit] your question with your Cassandra config, keyspace and table definition, as well as your insert statements as part of a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer Thanks for the follow up. I added the Keyspace and table details in the question. Also after running jar, the respective kafka topics for the table got created. But events where not able to seen in the kafka topics. So I just restarted my Cassandra database and run the jar again after that events are able seen in the kafka. So now for every new events after restarting the database only i am able to see the events in kafka topics. Did I need to add any configuration or missed any configuration for resolving this issue.